# Not able to set the JSON object of Arrays in React js using axios.get function and display the object of Arrays in table

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, key-value

I have JSON API like this-----

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "date": "2019/10/14",
            "a": "T",
            "b": "S",
        },
        {
            "date": "2020/10/14",
            "a": "T",
            "b": "S",
        }
              ]
}
```

I want to use this above JSONAPI to display the data in the Table using react js:
This is how I am displaying data from JSONAPI using axios.get function----

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';




class keyValue extends React.Component {
  state = { value: [],
    keyValues: []
 };

  componentDidMount() {   
      return axios.get(ApiURL)
      .then(res => {       
        const value= res.data.result;                     
        this.setState({ value});  
        console.log(value);       
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
  render(){ 

  return (

    <Paper >
     <Table aria-labelledby="DATA">
        <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center"></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"></TableCell>                 
          </TableRow>       
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>        
          {this.state.value.map((i) => (
            <TableRow key={i}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {i}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{this.state.value[i]}</TableCell> 

            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>

      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
}

export default KeyValue;
```

I want to display the output in the table in the following manner----

if index [0] is selected then the value should be

```
 date  2019/10/14
 a     T
 b     S
```

Issue---- I am not getting the below error in console when trying to set the value:-
**"Object doesn't support property or method 'map'"**

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.state.users`? It seems to be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood it completely

```
this.setState({...this.state, value: result})
```

and then try this

```
{this.state.value.map((v, i) => (
            <TableRow key={i}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {i}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{v.date}</TableCell> 

            </TableRow>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.value` is an array of objects, which means `i` is an object when you are using `this.state.value.map((i) =>`.

You are using it as an index: `this.state.value[i]`

Have a look at [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and either use `i` as an object, or use the second parameter for the index

I think you should update you code to something like this:

```
{this.state.value.map((val, index) => <TableRow key={index}>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
       date: {val.date}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
       a: {val.a}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
       b: {val.b} 
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
}
```

This will print the properties of each object in the `this.state.value` into each table cell. You can update this to suite your needs

Comment: This will print the all the key:value from object---  date: 2019/10/14 date:2019/10/14 a:T a: T b:S b:S.................. But I want to print value like 0th index of object ----- date  2019/10/14
 a     T
 b     S

Comment: That will be difficult with a map (you could do an if check on the index, but I wouldn't recommend that. If you let me know how you are working out which index to show, I'll try to update my answer). You're going to need another state variable that will hold the index most likely. Removing the need to map your results entirely